# Action Script 3.0 Score Counter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have been trying to make a score counter for a small game where the user clicks on a button on the stage, each time the user presses the button the score increments by 10, however I cannot get the score to display on the dynamic text field. What am I doing wrong?

```
var score:uint;
//scoreCounter is the instance name of the dynamic text box

    function updateScore():void{
     score += 10;
     scoreCounter.text = score.toString();
}
```

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code, including your button event callback.

Comment: //event listeners

var score:uint;
function updateScore():void{
  score += 10;
     scoreCounter.text = score.toString();
}
function stonePoint(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
updateScore();
scoreCounter.text = score.toString();
}}
//
function hatPoint(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
updateScore();
scoreCounter.text = score.toString();
}
}

Comment: Sorry its messy, but I cant answer my own question, I need at least 100 reputation or wait for 8 hours

Comment: You should be able to edit your questions though and could include it there... But it might be a simple problem of never setting score to 0? You need to initialize your variable or you are adding 10 to who knows what.

Comment: @ M.Laing that is a good point, but wouldn't setting .text to score.toString() make "null" or "undefined" show up in the text field in that case?

Comment: @DaveFisher you should just wait then if you have the answer. Delete your comment with the code as that's typically not desirable and most people won't read it anyway. :)

Comment: I don't know about is as3 what it will do for sure (I use it but not enough to know the behavior of not intializing a variable since I always do it because I'm used to c++).  I know in c++ if you don't initialize it to a value you will get strange results like huge numbers and stuff because it tries to look up its value but its just random mess at its memory location until your intialize it with a value.  So it could even be possible that the resulting string is just blank so it doesn't show up.

Comment: Did you embed the font for the text field?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell where your problem is because you really haven't posted enough code. Make sure your methods look something like this. This code is tested and working

```
package{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class Test extends Sprite{
    private var txt:TextField;
    private var score:uint = 0;
    public function Test()
    {
        //creating my text field
        txt = new TextField();
        addChild(txt);

        //drawing a black rectangle to use as a "button"
        var spt:Sprite = new Sprite();
        spt.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        spt.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        spt.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(spt);
        spt.y = 50;

        //adding the click event to the "button"
        spt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);

    }

    protected function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //adding 10 to score
        score += 10;
        //setting the txt text field to score
        txt.text = score.toString();


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure your embedding fonts if in your textfield. to test if its working at all you can do:

```
 scoreCounter.embedFonts = false;
```

see if it displays then.